# How to reload java classes in intellij idea for maven web app

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In eclipse, I can start web app like below by debug running 'tomcat7:run'.

[image]

In this way, when I changed the code like method body of servlet, it will be taken into effect immediately. But today when I switched to intellj idea. I also start the server with debug option like below.

[image].

When I changed the method, the new code does not work. How can I solve this problem since this functionality is very important for me. I guess intellj idea will support this feature easily if I use built-in support for tomcat. But I am using maven style webapp now. I spent about 2 hours to be a bit famililar with this new IDE, I hope I will not give it up due to the debug issue. Thanks.

Comment: HotSwap/Reload is supported for IntelliJ IDEA Tomcat configuration and exploded artifacts only: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: Thanks. Does it support maven web app?

Comment: I'm not sure what is "maven web app". Maven projects with war packaging are imported automatically and artifacts are generated by IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you in hot swapping the code midway execution(in debug mode)
[image]

Using the above feature, the code will automatically build on its own as soon as the modifications are saved in the file. And based on the modified artifacts, the deployment to the locally running container(embedded tomcat) will also happen. And as a result, you need not have to restart after each small modification of code.

Above setting can be found at - IntelliJ -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> HotSwap